# Replace value with NA based on whether variable matches an item in a vector(

Tags: r

My question is more about how to improve what I suspect is inefficient code.

I have two dataframes: one contains data on county-level disaster information and the other contains data on county-level income per-capita. As a first step, I am interested in identifying for which counties we are missing per-capita income data. Here is what that looks like with sample dataframes:

```
counties <- data.frame(polyname = c("alabama,autauga","alabama,autauga",
                                    "alabama,baldwin","alabama,baldwin",
                                    "alabama,barbour","alabama,barbour", 
                                    "alabama,bibb", "alabama,bibb"), 
                       indAnyDisaster_frequency = c("1-2", "1-2", "0", "0", 
                                                   "3-5", "3-5", "1-2","1-2"))
counties_persinc_1980 <- data.frame(polyname = c("alabama,autauga","alabama,autauga",
                                                 "alabama,baldwin","alabama,baldwin",
                                                 "alabama,barbour","alabama,barbour", 
                                                 "alabama,bibb", "alabama,bibb"), 
                                    persinc_1980 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 25, 30, 32, 28))
no_persinc_1980 <- unique(counties_persinc_1980$polyname[is.na(counties_persinc_1980$persinc_1980)])
```

Now, I want to use the vector of missing county names to replace counties$indAnyDisaster_frequency with NA if the counties$polyname of the same index matches an element of the vector. I believe I have been able to achieve this with a for-loop, but I don't believe it is very efficient. However, I have not been able to figure out how to use lapply to achieve the same outcome. I've included both the code for the loop and one of my attempts at using lapply.

```
for(i in 1:length(no_persinc_1980)){
  counties$indAnyDisaster_frequency[counties$polyname==no_persinc_1980[i]] <- NA
}
lapply(1:length(no_persinc_1980), function(x) counties$indAnyDisaster_frequency[counties$polyname==no_persinc_1980[x]] <- NA)
```

Any guidance on how to improve this approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
idx <- which(counties$polyname %in% no_persinc_1980)
counties[ idx, 'indAnyDisaster_frequency' ] <- NA
```

Comment: Good answer. I had a similar thought. Just as a note, you don't need `which` here because `%in%` returns a logical vector. You can use a logical vector to index rows, so no need to find the row number with `which`.

Comment: @AndS You are 100% correct, but I've adopted the convention of always using `which` to ensure I have a vector of numeric indices rather than a vector of logical because I've encountered situations where the latter results in confusion.

Answer (score 1):

No loop necessary. I would look into `%in%`

```r
counties$indAnyDisaster_frequency[counties$polyname %in% no_persinc_1980] <- NA

counties
#>          polyname indAnyDisaster_frequency
#> 1 alabama,autauga                     <NA>
#> 2 alabama,autauga                     <NA>
#> 3 alabama,baldwin                     <NA>
#> 4 alabama,baldwin                     <NA>
#> 5 alabama,barbour                      3-5
#> 6 alabama,barbour                      3-5
#> 7    alabama,bibb                      1-2
#> 8    alabama,bibb                      1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Pull the names of counties with `NA` in column `persinc_1980`

```
counties_nas <- counties_persinc_1980 %>% 
  filter(is.na(persinc_1980)) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pull(polyname)
```

Change `indAnyDisaster_frequency` into `NA` if polyname exists in the vector

```
counties %>%  
  mutate(indAnyDisaster_frequency = case_when(polyname %in% counties_nas ~ NA_character_, 
                                              TRUE ~ indAnyDisaster_frequency))

  polyname        indAnyDisaster_frequency
  <chr>           <chr>                   
1 alabama,autauga NA                      
2 alabama,autauga NA                      
3 alabama,baldwin NA                      
4 alabama,baldwin NA                      
5 alabama,barbour 3-5                     
6 alabama,barbour 3-5                     
7 alabama,bibb    1-2                     
8 alabama,bibb    1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend joining the two data frames together.  It's almost always the best way to go about things.

```r
library(tidyverse)

counties <- data.frame(polyname = c("alabama,autauga","alabama,autauga",
                                    "alabama,baldwin","alabama,baldwin",
                                    "alabama,barbour","alabama,barbour", 
                                    "alabama,bibb", "alabama,bibb"), 
                       indAnyDisaster_frequency = c("1-2", "1-2", "0", "0", 
                                                    "3-5", "3-5", "1-2","1-2"))

counties_persinc_1980 <- data.frame(polyname = c("alabama,autauga","alabama,autauga",
                                                 "alabama,baldwin","alabama,baldwin",
                                                 "alabama,barbour","alabama,barbour", 
                                                 "alabama,bibb", "alabama,bibb"), 
                                    persinc_1980 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 25, 30, 32, 28))

# join
disasters <- left_join(counties, counties_persinc_1980, by = "polyname")
print(disasters)
#>           polyname indAnyDisaster_frequency persinc_1980
#> 1  alabama,autauga                      1-2           NA
#> 2  alabama,autauga                      1-2           NA
#> 3  alabama,autauga                      1-2           NA
#> 4  alabama,autauga                      1-2           NA
#> 5  alabama,baldwin                        0           NA
#> 6  alabama,baldwin                        0           NA
#> 7  alabama,baldwin                        0           NA
#> 8  alabama,baldwin                        0           NA
#> 9  alabama,barbour                      3-5           25
#> 10 alabama,barbour                      3-5           30
#> 11 alabama,barbour                      3-5           25
#> 12 alabama,barbour                      3-5           30
#> 13    alabama,bibb                      1-2           32
#> 14    alabama,bibb                      1-2           28
#> 15    alabama,bibb                      1-2           32
#> 16    alabama,bibb                      1-2           28

# which missing
disasters %>% 
  filter(is.na(persinc_1980)) %>%
  pull(polyname) %>% 
  unique()
#> [1] "alabama,autauga" "alabama,baldwin"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Notice that you joined on a non unique column, so you end up with more rows than both the data frames. I don't think this has the intended result for the question.

Comment: Good point.  Maybe it's an error in the example though.  I can't imagine how a single county can have two different observations of per-capita income in 1980.